# How to replace loading a script file with an Ajax call in JavaScript (using YQL with JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, yql

!!! The question below has been answered by Andrew Whitaker's response (great example). Basically you can use $.getJSON(..) to programatically fetch JSON data from a service such as YQL, noting that this service can be associated with a different domain (i.e., not provided by the same domain from which the page was loaded). Normally, you cannot make such a request to a different domain and thus a "trick" is used in implementing the request where HTML is dynamically generated and inserted into the DOM and new cross-domain script is fetched and executed. In executing the returned script, it causes the JSON carried with it to be processed and your supplied callback function called. Because this technique blindly executes returned script, one must be careful of security concerns (probably similar to loading any script). In order to enable the cross-domain ability, it is IMPORTANT in the provided getJSON url to include the option "?callback=?", which is picked up and removed/modified by jQuery as a signal to use the JSONP cross-domain calling technique. Note that this method of returning JSON data relies on server-side support of JSONP. Thanks again for all the help. !!!

The following code goes out to YQL and fetches the current stock price of IBM (as an example). It works fine and does its task by loading a script file whose URL effectively causes the dynamic generation of JSON data, which upon loading and executing, causes 'top_stories' to be run and the price extracted. However, I would like to make this process based on an AJAX call ($.getJSON(..)) where I presume I separate out the url and data components from the below script-based example. I've tried a lot of variations without success--it doesn't seem like I can get the $.getJSON(..) call to call the callback function. Any thoughts would be appreciated.
...Eric

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
  <head><title>YQL</title>
   <style type='text/css'>
    #results{ width: 40%; margin-left: 30%; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px; height: 200px; overflow: auto; } 
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  // Parses returned response 
  function top_stories(o) {
      var price = o.query.results.xml_api_reply.finance.last.data;
      alert("last = " + price);
      // Place price in div tag
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = price;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Div tag for stories results -->
   <div id='results'></div>
   <!-- The YQL statment will be assigned to src. -->
   <script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20google.igoogle.stock%20where%20stock%3D'ibm'%3B&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=top_stories"></script>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lookup same origin policy, which you're violating.

Comment: I have tried the code provided by the respondents below (thanks!) and found that it works under Chrome but not IE (including the jsfiddle site example--what was neat). I tried disabling IE's XSS filter, the firewall, and minimizing IE's security setting but this did not help.

Comment: The above code works I guess because it is essentially JSONP (if I understand it) in that one is by passing the "same origin policy" restriction using a script tag. I can see adding DOM entries to dynamically generate the script tags and thus fetch the data, but this seems a round about way of doing things. I read up on CORS but did exactly follow what I should be doing. If you want general code without introducing security risks (JSONP) that will run on most browsers, is there a best way to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code:

```
    $(function () {
    var ticker = "IBM";
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%3D'"+ticker+"'&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data.query.results.quote, function(key, val) {
        if(key == "ChangePercentRealtime" || key == "LastTradeRealtimeWithTime") { items.push(val)};
      });
        $("#nameOfDiv1").html(items[0].substr(9));
        $("#nameOfDiv2").html(items[1].substr(6));
    });
});
```

The substr() gets the actual data from the returned results which contains some non-useful things. It puts it in some html divs. You can pick whatever resultset you want obviously. Hope it helps u!

Comment: You can and should pick those two fields directly in the query instead, but this was just some code I had testing things with before...

Comment: Thanks! Please see my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but here's how you could break out the querystring parameters into a "data" object:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?", {
    q: "select * from google.igoogle.stock where stock='ibm'",
    format: 'json',
    diagnostics: true,
    env: 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
}, top_stories);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dcXjk/1/

As an aside, if you are using jQuery anyway you can go ahead and use `.html` instead assigning directly to `innerHTML`:

```
function top_stories(o) {
    var price = o.query.results.xml_api_reply.finance.last.data;
    alert("last = " + price);
    // Place price in div tag
    $("#results").html(price);
}
```

---

Here's a more fleshed out example where you can pass in the stock symbol as well:

**JavaScript:**

```
function top_stories(o, symbol) {
    var price = o.query.results.xml_api_reply.finance.last.data;

    // Place price in div tag
    $("#" + symbol).html(price);
}

function getStockValue(symbol) {
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=?", {
        q: "select * from google.igoogle.stock where stock='" + symbol + "'",
        format: 'json',
        diagnostics: true,
        env: 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
    }, function(data) {
        top_stories(data, symbol);
    });
}


$(function() {
    getStockValue("ibm");
    getStockValue("nflx");
    getStockValue("msft");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>IBM:</p><div id="ibm"></div>
<p>Netflix:</p><div id="nflx"></div>
<p>Microsoft:</p><div id="msft"></div>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/B3L4p/1/

Comment: Thanks! Please see my comments above.

Comment: @EricSchneider: I forgot an important part of using `$.getJSON`. Please see my updated code/examples. They should work in IE now, sorry about that!

Comment: Your solution does indeed work now in IE! Thanks very much for the help and really great examples above.